# ImportError: No module named builtins

Tags: 14.04, python3

I am porting my python application from python 2 to python 3.
As python-3 provides utility `2to3` which converts python-2 code to python-3.
`import builtins`  giving error as

```
ImportError: No module named builtins
```

Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 12):

Solved a similar error in a separate situation by installing the package `future`.

```
sudo pip install future
```

It's not clear if your error occurs when running 2to3 or when trying to run the resulting code. If it is when running 2to3 it is likely because it's actually using `python2` (the default) and thus if you haven't installed the `future`, `builtins` will be missing. Similarly if you are trying to run the resulting code with `python2` the same error might occur.

Answer (score 3):

The `2to3` tool generates code compatible with Python 3-only.

You're probably seeing that because you're running the converted code in Python 2.

If you want your code to be compatible with Python 2 and 3, you can do this instead:

```
try:
    import builtins
except ImportError:
    import __builtin__ as builtins
```